# Two-dimensional array issue

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

In this simple 1D array program, both &p and p are working with %s in the scanf statement. It is not showing any error.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{   
    char p[5];
    scanf("%s",&p);
    printf("%s",p);
    scanf("%s",p);
    printf("%s",p); 
    return 0;
}
```

But in a 2D array of characters it is showing an error. Why?
For example:
here, `masterlist` is a two-dimensional array of characters.
Why is this code working?

```
for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    scanf("%s",&masterlist[i][0]);
```

And why is this code not working? Why is the compiler not showing any errors?

```
for(i=0;i<5;i++)
   scanf("%s",masterlist[i][0]);
```

**Actual code :** My program is working, I just want to know what I asked above. Thanks.

```
#include<string.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#define FOUND 1
#define NOTFOUND 0
int main()
{
char masterlist[6][10]={"akshay","parag","raman","srinivas","gopal","rajesh"};
int i,flag,a;
char yourname[10];
printf("Enter your Name:");
scanf("%s",yourname);
flag=NOTFOUND;
for(i=0;i<=5;i++)
{  
    a=strcmp(&masterlist[i][0],yourname);
    if(a==0)
    {
        printf("Welcome,you can Enter The place\n");
        flag=FOUND;
        break;

    }
    }

    if(flag==NOTFOUND)
    printf("Sorry,Yoy are a trespasser\n");
    return 0;

    }
```

Comment: How have you defined and allocated your masterlist?

Comment: You are scanned only one `char` . then why did you write `%s`.

Comment: You are trying to store a string in a char

Comment: Can you show me declaration of `masterlist`..

Comment: @ANBU.SANKAR chek the edited code

Comment: try with `[i][10]` Instead of `[i][0]`..This suggestion is for `scanf` ...

Comment: In actual code try like this at place of `strcmp`...    `a=strcmp(masterlist[i],yourname);`

Comment: @ANBU.SANKAR my concern in not my actual program .my program is working...i want to know the answer for my first part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

print this and then see the output hope you will understand why `&` is required in case of `2D`:

```
printf("&yourname = %p\n",&yourname);
printf("yourname = %p\n",yourname);
printf("&masterlist[i][0] = %p\n",&masterlist[0][0]);
printf("masterlist[i][0] = %p\n",masterlist[0][0]);
```

--> `masterlist[i][0]` points the first character of `ith` row of your `2D` array which is not a address where you can store value string.

--> `&masterlist[i][0]` points the  `ith` row of your `2D` array which is address where you can store sequence of `char` i.e string.

but in case of `1D` array i.e `yourname` contains base address of `yourname` array so you can store a sequence of character there.

Comment: Can you give me reason for that

Comment: Thanks Rustam for your Explanation

Comment: @AbhishekWalter u welcome.  and if it is clear for you then hope you will accept my answer

Comment: don't print pointers with `%d`, this is wrong and depending on the width of the different types can cause crashes and whatever. Use `%p` for that.

Answer (score 4):

In your first example you use `p` and `&p` which are pointers that both point to `p[0]`.

In your last example, `masterlist[i][0]` is equivalent to `p[0]`, which is a `char`, and hence the parameter sent to `printf` is promoted to `int`. Scan code `"%s"` needs a pointer to writable memory. It is highly unlikely that `masterlist[i][0]` will point to writable memory.

Not all compilers check scan codes to `printf`. Some do, and with the appropriate warning level you will get a warning. Try to add `-Wall` to the compiler command line, it turns up the warning level for `gcc` and a few other compilers.